# Autorun a python with sudo at startup

Tags: macos, mac, python, osx-yosemite

How can I make a python script rusn at startup on my OS X Yosemite Macbook every time? I want it to have sudo privilages as well.

Answer (score 0):

The proper place for this sort of commands is the file */etc/rc.local*: you make your file executable (*chmod 755 NameOfFile*), place the line

```
  /Full/Path/To/File
```

inside the */etc/rc.local* file, and that's it.

However, beginning with Yosemite, */etc/rc.local* is not honored any longer. To counteract this, place the follwoing file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
     <key>Label</key>             <string>local.localhost.startup</string>
     <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
     <key>KeepAlive</key>         <false/>
     <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <true/>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
          <string>/etc/rc.local</string>
       </array>
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

as /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.localhost.startup.plist  At this point, though, you must also make sure that */etc/rc.local* is executable.